# Distributed processing of records in a relational database

Tags: mysql, architecture, distributed-computing

I have a MySQL database table with several million records like below:

```
item_id   processing_time
1         01:30:00
2         16:50:00
3         23:24:00
```

The processing_time column indicates the time that the record should be processed every day.

There is a cron job scheduled (using the quartz library) that runs every five minutes and processes records from the table. Each time the job runs it queries for records with processing_times within the next five minutes and processes them.

Right now this job runs only on a single server with the workload split across multiple threads. Due to the number of records that need to processed, I would like to distribute the job across multiple servers in addition to threads.

My question is how I can distribute the job across multiple servers and ensure that each record is only processed by a single server.

The first solution I thought of is to assign each record in the item table a processing node (1-n) and store this relationship in another table. E.g. the schema might look like this:

```
item_id   processing_node
1         1
2         2
3         3
...
```

Each time a new item is created there would be a corresponding record inserted in the item_processing_node table. Since processing times are not evenly distributed, there would also need to be some kind of an algorithm used to ensure even distribution among processing nodes of items with the same processing times.

The second solution I can think of is use a queuing architecture. One node (the master node) queries for items to process and inserts them into the queue. All nodes then read items from the queue.

Any thoughts on either of these solutions and which one is preferred?

Comment: What approach did you end up choosing, could you please add it as an answer to your own question?

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely looking for a queueing architecture, it's a standard pattern when you have a distributed processing system, especially since it's batch-mode.